# Big O time complexity of looping over a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, big-o

I'm trying to figure out the time complexity of looping over a list of dictionaries and then further each dictionary key.

An example is:

```
n = [
  { 'a': a, 'b': b, ...},
  { 'a': a, 'b': b, ...},
]

def solve(n):
  for item in n:
     for key in item:
       ....
```

I'm inclined to say that this is O(n^2) where by the worst case is affected by the size of the list and the number of key: value pairs in each dictionary.

Is this correct?

Comment: If there are `n` keys in each of the dictionary, then yes, it's O(n^2), otherwise it's O(nk) where `k` is the number of keys for each dictionary.

Comment: What would this be called?  Linear?

Comment: Linear is `x^1`, you have `x^2`, so this would be quadratic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your runtime complexity is `O(n) * O(k)` where:

- `n` is n (the list length)
- `k` the number of items per list element (could be different from n)

So, your complexity is indeed `n²`, **but** only if `k` is approximately equal to `n`.